# In my google chrome for mac, CMD + Shift + r to reload the current webpage does not work?

Tags: macos, keyboard, google-chrome

This [Google Chrome keyboard shortcuts support page](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179?hl=en), in the Mac > Webpage shortcuts section, indicates:

> Reload your current page, ignoring cached content:    ⌘ + Shift + r

But that keyboard shortcut does not work for me, my mac only beeps when I press those buttons.

⌘ + r works as expected, but ⌘ + Shift + r only beeps.

I'm lost how to fix this. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm on macOS High Sierra in case its relevant.

Comment: Maybe the page has no cached content? Although it does work for me.

Comment: ⌘ + Shift + r works fine for me, using Chrome on High Sierra. Is it possible you've set that key combination to do something else in the Keyboard pane in System Preferences? That would override the Chrome setting. Or perhaps you have something else installed (maybe a Chrome plugin) that is overriding that shortcut?

Comment: Same here – El Capitan 10.11.6, Chrome Version 64.0.3282.140. I can't reload using ignore cache mode, my machine beeps when I do the combo. Edit: tried to disable all extensions, the problem persist.

Comment: Found the problem, in my case was caused by 'Be Focused' app, it overrides the ⌘ + Shift + r shortcut as it is used to start a new timer.

Comment: @Manu you are an absolute legend. I use that Chrome short cut all the time and it suddenly stopped working. The culprit was the 'Be Focused' app!!!

Comment: @Manu ++ It was driving me nuts for a week on the new work laptop! I've been using Be Focused for a long time, but with customized key combos.  And I guess I missed that app's preferences when migrating from the old machine.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### In most cases, the reason is, that another application does already listening to the same shortcut.

> In my case it was another running application called Be Focused (Pro) which uses the same shortcut (`CTRL+CMD+R`) defined as a global shortcut per default.

### 1.) Try to close a bunch of running applications

1. Try closing all other running applications. Even the apps which has only an icon in the macOS tray area.
2. Try the problematic shortcut after a restart of Google Chrome (`chrome://restart`)
3. If the shortcut works now, you know that at least one of the closed applications listening to that shortcut and prevents it from working in Google Chrome.

### 2.) Try to open program for program and test the problematic shortcut in Google Chrome (after a restart) if it still works.

> When you found the responsible application, try to adjust their shortcut configuration.

Comment: You're a rockstar - literally just downloaded the Be Focused app and was so confused why my `CTRL+CMD+R` just randomly stopped working. 

Thanks for figuring this out!

Comment: +1 Installed the same app and had this issue. I was able to unset the shortcut and now chrome's shortcut works fine.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I need to `Turn On` my Developer Mode.

To turn on Developer Mode on Google Chrome.

1. Open your Google Chrome.
2. Navigate to `chrome://extensions/`
3. `Turn On` Developer Mode on your Top right hand Corner.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  We like to see answers that are more than 1 sentence.  Why does turn on developer mode help?  How can you turn on developer mode?  Some people with this problem won't know now to do what you're suggesting.

Comment: @fsb Thanks for your Feedback. I have elaborated my Solution.